# NSURL nil when unwrapping an optional value | character not working?

Tags: swift, nsurl, nsurlrequest

```
let urlstr = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key={key}&with_genres=28|27|80|12|53|10752&sort_by=popularity.desc&page=\(pageNum)"
```

string looks like this:

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?api_key={key}&with_genres=28|27|80|12|53|10752&sort_by=popularity.desc&page=1
```

and works fine when I copy and paste in browser
but when I try to create a NSURL it returns nil

```
let url = NSURL(string: urlstr)
```

I tried to erase | from the string and that actually worked, but i need that for my request so I can't do that, is there any way past this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "way past this" is to supply a *legal* URL string. Yours is illegal, because of the pipe characters - as you have rightly deduced - so you are going to get a `nil` result from `NSURL(string: urlstr)`.

Simply replace all those pipes by the equivalent percent-escape sequence and all will be well. You can get NSURL to help you by calling `NSURL(scheme:host:path:)` instead.